# Анимированное добавление и удаление класса у блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Хочу сделать анимированное добавление класса и его удаление. в гугле нашел инфу про `transition`, но почему-то не работает. как сделать?

```js
$('button.add').click(function() {
  $('div.required').addClass('required-empty');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('div.required').removeClass('required-empty');
            }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.required {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.required:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  left: -18px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #e0e0e3;
  content: "R";
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.required:after {
   content: "";
}

.required.required-red:before {
  color: #fa6464;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.required-empty {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.required-empty:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  right: -18px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #fa6464;
  content: "s";
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="required required-red">

</div>
<button class="add">addClass</button>
```

Comment: и что тут не работает, не понятно?

Comment: Собственно, a что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @Air уже сделал ибо.